# combine multiple GET values with same variable name into one string

Tags: php, forms, url

I have a form which sends lots of GET['var'] in a form.

Ive worked out how to set it to send var[1]=data&var[2]=some&var[3]=thing etc etc

but how do I catch each variable and combine it into one string, seperated with a ", "?

so $var = data, some, thing

**UPDATE**:

Sorry I should of mentioned I already have the function that implodes the string but I dont know how to combine all the Var[n]'s into one $var string.

Hope this makes sense!

**Solved!**

Thanks Kazar, your first answer actually worked a treat! it required me altering my script a little but your way certainly makes sense to me now

Comment: Do you know the no. of var[?] parameters you are sending?

Comment: Can we have a sample of what you want the resulting string to look like?

Comment: bit silly of me not to just use implode in the first place

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The php [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function will concatenate the contents of an array together, using a string to insert between them, like so:

```
$var = implode(',', $_GET['var']);
```

An additional note, the order in which the various elements of var appear does depend on the order in the querystring, so a string could come out looking like 'var2,var0,var1'.  To get round this, you may want to do a key sort first:

```
$var = $_GET['var'];
ksort($var);
$joinedString = implode(',', $var);
```

**Edit**: According to the question edit:

Assuming you mean to create the query string again...?

```
$var = $_GET['var'];
$components = array();

foreach($var as $key=>$value) {

  $components[] = "var[" . $key . "]=" . $value;

}

$string = implode('&', $components);
```

Might help to have a more detailed description.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [implode function](http://pt.php.net/implode) that concatenates the contents of an array.

```
$var = implode (',', $var);
```